# is this an efficient way to parseInt?

Tags: javascript, performance

Is this the best way to convert a string to an Int
in a do while loop?I think my code in parseInt is an inefficient way because it makes the computer parseInt everytime until the dowhile loop is true

```
function randomUpper(upper) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * upper) + 1
}

var limit = 10;
var guess;
var randomNumber = randomUpper(limit);
var guessMade = 0;

do{
    guess = prompt("Guess the number");
    guess = parseInt(guess);
    guessMade++;
} while (guess !== randomNumber);

document.write(guessMade)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "efficient" actually?

Comment: can you clarify this "inefficient way because it makes the computer parseInt everytime until the dowhile loop is true"

Comment: Instead of parsing the int every time, you could just convert the `randomNumber` to a string. So, it would be `var randomNumber = ''+randomUpper(limit);` instead of `var randomNumber = randomUpper(limit);` String comparisons should be pretty fast.

Comment: I mean is this the way to do convert a string into an int in a dowhile loop???because I think the computer works harder because im parsing the string every time I loop...Is this the only way in javascript?

Comment: Or you can be really naughty and use the `!=` operator instead of the `!==` operator so that it does type conversion of the `guess` automatically.

Comment: @AcidCoder it works "harder" than *what*?

Comment: @4castle that's the same thing... ;-;

Comment: There is no way the computer "works hard" in a loop that includes user interaction via `prompt`. In the time it takes the user to type a number, you could parse millions of integers.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is such a high level language that things like string to integer type coercions don't put that much stress on the language.

You can't avoid a type coercion either. To compare a string to an integer properly, at some point they have to be the same type (loose comparison aside), meaning you have to convert it manually as strict comparison won't compare it otherwise.

This really shouldn't be a concern, especially when you're using `prompt`, a user input function that awaits feedback from the browser window. That's a whole lot more expensive than string to integer conversion.